# How to use REGEXP_LIKE in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, case

I'd like to use REGEXP_LIKE in my CASE statement

**2 Questions**

1. How can I get REGEXP_LIKE to work in this CASE statement?
   I'm getting the following error message
   `ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier`
2. Re regex, why does the `select '12345678' from dual` query return `1`?

**Regex Rule**

0 to 6 digits,followed by 0 or 1 decimal point, followed by 0 to six digits.

```
with expression_row as 
(select 'zzzz'     as expression from dual union all
select '12345678' as expression from dual union all
select '12.33333' as expression from dual union all
select '.222222'  as expression from dual)
select 
expression,
       case regexp_like( expression, '^\d{0,6}(\.{0,1}\d{0,6})$') 
      -- [0-6 digits][0-1 decimal][0-6 digits]
       when TRUE then 'Y'
       else 'N'
      end as valid_y_n
    from expression_row;
```

**Desired Output**

```
zzzz     N
12345678 N
12.33333 Y
.222222  Y
```

I'm validating my regex pattern using this query.

```
select 1 as valid from dual 
where regexp_like( '12345678', '^\d{0,6}\.{0,1}\d{0,6}$');
```

Comment: Your expression is matching `78` in `12345678` for the fact that you begin matching `^` start of line, `0-6` digits, and then looking for a decimal `0 or 1` time which is the same as making it optional e.g `\.?`, followed by `0-6` digits. If you don't want it to match then remove the `{0,1}` e.g `^\d{0,6}(\.\d{0,6})$`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Try the code below - it's not the regex that's wrong so much as where it's located.  SQL works in a different way to most languages when evaluating expressions - it doesn't return true and then compare that with other values; you need to put the condition that returns true in the place where a condition or value is expected.

```
with expression_row as 
(select 'zzzz'     as expression from dual union all
select '12345678' as expression from dual union all
select '12.33333' as expression from dual union all
select '.222222'  as expression from dual)
select 
expression
,case 
   when regexp_like( expression, '^\d{0,6}(\.{0,1}\d{0,6})$')  -- [0-6 digits][0-1 decimal][0-6 digits]
   then 'Y'
   else 'N'
end as valid_y_n
from expression_row;
```

2) 1 is SQL speak for TRUE; 0 is FALSE.  This is because SQL uses bits instead of bools (though they're the same from a logic perspective).

Answer (score 0):

Use  `case when regex_instr(variable, 'regex') <> 0 then ...` instead.

```
with expression_row as 
(select 'zzzz'     as expression from dual union all
select '12345678' as expression from dual union all
select '12.33333' as expression from dual union all
select '.222222'  as expression from dual)
select 
expression,
       case when regexp_instr(expression, '^\d{0,6}(\.{0,1}\d{0,6})$') <> 0 
          then 'Y' 
          else 'N'  
      end as valid_y_n
    from expression_row;
```